# HTML alignment for every platform

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web page which have images in rows and columns.
so far i have covered the images but alignment is not good.I mean if there were large screens it will be alright,but for short screens it does not suit and alignment is pretty much out of width. i just want the images to adjust as the screens differ.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
 #arr
 {
     width:auto;
     margin-top:150px;
     margin-bottom:30px;
     height:auto;

}

 .left1
 {
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     float:left;
     margin-left:40px;
 }
 .left2
 {
     width:200px;
     margin-left:30px;
     height:250px;
     float:left;
 }
 .left3
 {
     width:200px;
     margin-left:30px;
     height:250px;
     float:left;
 }
 .left4
 {
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     float:left;
     margin-left:30px;
 }
 .left5
 {
     width:200px;
     margin-left:30px;
     height:250px;
     float:left;
     margin-right:40px;
 }


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="left1">
<img src="Images/1TheShawshankRedemption.jpeg" alt="" width="200" height="250" title="The Shawshank Redemption (1994)"  >

</div>
<div class="left2">
<img src="Images/2TheGodFather.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="250" title="The God Father (1972)" >
</div>
<div class="left3">
<img src="Images/3TheGodFather2.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="250" title="The God Father Part 2 (1974)" >
</div>
<div class="left4">
<img src="Images/4TheDarkKnight.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="250" title="The Dark Knight (2008)" >
</div>
<div class="left5">
<img src="Images/5PulpFiction.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="250" title="Pulp Fiction(1994)" >
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could try `img {max-width: 100%};` that will scale down your images without loosing the ratio.

Comment: Images are coming well i think there is no scaling required for images.problem comes when if I select high resolution monitor,it appears as 5 images in a row but if i select low resolution such as tablet,it appears as 4 images in a row and other image in another row and that image is right below the first image in the first row and there is no padding or anything.please if you have time once go through my code

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I created a new fiddle, from what I understand from you. You wish all the images to be on the same line, no matter the width of the window, right? In order to do that you need to remove the width in pixels and use percentage instead. Also remove the height from images. http://jsfiddle.net/Lgkhd9yb/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to shrink and grow without changing the `height:width` ratio, you could use the `max-width` property in CSS.

```
div > img {
    max-width: 100% /* You could change it from 100% to something else if you want*/
}
```

Comment: Images are coming well i think there is no scaling required for images.problem comes when if I select high resolution monitor,it appears as 5 images in a row but if i select low resolution such as tablet,it appears as 4 images in a row and other image in another row and that image is right below the first image in the first row and there is no padding or anything.please if you have time once go through my code

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?